# opening hours table design postgresql: how to query this?

Tags: postgresql

I want to store opening hours of a store in a PostgreSQL database. I have a few question about this. First of all, my table design:

```
Table: opening_hours
--------------------
* id
* store_id
* start_day (0->6)
* start_time (HH:mm:ss)
* duration (HH:mm:ss)
* timezone (default: Europe/Brussels)

Example:
--------
1    1    0    08:00:00    12:00:00    Europe/Brussels
// store ID 1 is open on sundays from 08AM to 08PM (12 hours in total) local time
2    2    6    20:00:00    04:00:00    Europe/Brussels
// store ID 2 is open on saturday from 08PM till 04AM (on sunday) (this is like a pub or something with opening hours at night) local time (so 20:00:00 in Belgium open = 19:00:00 in London open)
```

I think this is a good design, because now I can make opening hours spanning more than 1 day (like when a pub is open at night). Before that, I was storing opening hours in each day separately so I had to enter 'saturday 20:00:00 -> 23:59:59' + 'sunday 00:00:00 -> 04:00:00' for the opening hours for store ID 2.

How can I query against these rows?
I want to check if a time already exists in the database before adding a new one, and I want to check if a row exists based on the current time of the user (2 different queries).

```
CURRENT ROWS:
-------------
1    1    1    08:00:00    08:00:00    Europe/Brussels
// open on monday from 08AM until 04PM
2    1    6    20:00:00    12:00:00    Europe/Brussels
// open on saturday from 08PM until sunday 08AM
NEW ROWS:
---------
3    1    1    14:00:00    04:00:00    Europe/Brussels (should not insert this row because it interferes with row ID 1)
// open on monday from 02PM until 06PM
4    1    1    17:00:00    04:00:00    Europe/Brussels (can insert because not interference with row 1)
// open on monday from 05PM until 09PM
5    1    0    07:00:00    05:00:00    Europe/Brussels (can't insert this row because it interferes with row 2).
// open on sunday from 07AM until 12PM
```

I hope my question is clear. If not, please correct me, I'll try to ask it differently then.

Answer (score 1):

With your new table design actually, it is now a bit tricky, because of durations that can possibly span over the end of a week cycle. Consider for example:

```
 start_day | start_time | duration 
-----------+------------+----------
         6 | 14:00:00   | 18:00:00
```

It actually extends into `day=0`, so it would need to match `day=0, t=07:00:00`.

When looking for matches against a specific time, you need to check two possibilities (either `day, time` or `day + 7, time` fall into one of your intervals). Same thing for overlaps (3 possibilities).

You can define some helper functions:

```sql
-- oh: opening hours helper functions

-- oh_tst: convert dow, time into a timestamp after the Epoch
-- (note: Epoch was not a Monday (dow 0), but it doesn't matter,
-- we could use any arbitrary date)
create or replace function oh_tst(dow int, t time) returns timestamp as $$
  select '1970-01-01'::timestamp + $1 * interval'1 day' + $2;
$$
language sql immutable;

-- oh_single_matches: internal function (no handling of wrap around)
create or replace function oh_single_matches(start_day int, start_time time, d interval, day int, t time) returns boolean as $$
  select oh_tst($4, $5) between oh_tst($1, $2) and oh_tst($1, $2) + $3 - interval'1 millisecond';
$$
language sql immutable;

-- oh_matches: tests if a (day, time) is within an oh interval
-- handle wrap around at end of week
create or replace function oh_matches(start_day int, start_time time, d interval, day int, t time) returns boolean as $$
  select oh_single_matches($1, $2, $3, $4, $5)
  or     oh_single_matches($1, $2, $3, $4, $5 + 7);
$$
language sql immutable;

-- oh_overlaps: test for oh defs overlap (incl wrap-around)
create or replace function oh_overlaps(adow int, astart_time time, aduration interval,
                                       bdow int, bstart_time time, bduration interval) returns boolean as $$
  select (oh_tst($1, $2), $3) overlaps (oh_tst($4, $5), $6)
  or     (oh_tst($1, $2), $3) overlaps (oh_tst($4 + 7, $5), $6)
  or     (oh_tst($1, $2), $3) overlaps (oh_tst($4 - 7, $5), $6);
$$
language sql immutable;
```

**Examples**:

Single match (one `day,time` against an opening hours definition):

```
-- intervals are left-close:
select oh_matches(6, '14:00:00'::time, interval'2 hours', 6, '14:00:00'::time);
 oh_matches 
------------
 t

-- ...and right-open (as Nature intended):
select oh_matches(6, '14:00:00'::time, interval'2 hours', 6, '15:59:59'::time);
 t

select oh_matches(6, '14:00:00'::time, interval'2 hours', 6, '16:00:00'::time);
 f

-- wrap around the end of week
select oh_matches(6, '14:00:00'::time, interval'18 hours', 0, '02:00:00'::time);
 t
```

Interval overlaps:

```
select oh_overlaps(2, '14:00:00'::time, interval'8 hours',
                   2, '04:00:00'::time, interval'8 hours');
 f

select oh_overlaps(2, '14:00:00'::time, interval'8 hours',
                   2, '08:00:00'::time, interval'8 hours');
 t

-- wraparoud ok
select oh_overlaps(0, '01:00:00'::time, interval'8 hours',
                   6, '22:00:00'::time, interval'18 hours');
 t
```

**Test against a table**:

Single timestamp (`now()`):

```
select * from mytable
where store_id=5
and oh_matches(start_day, start_time, duration, now()::timestamp);
```

Check if prospective rows in a `candidates` table would overlap existing definitions in `mytable`:

```
select * from candidates a inner join mytable b using (store_id)
where oh_overlaps(b.start_day, b.start_time, b.duration,
                  a.start_day, a.start_time, a.duration);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I will take a look at it now, because I do not understand everything you're writing down (I'm a postgresql beginner). I'm going to take a few hours to test it all. Thank you again!